# Azure webapp custom domain SSL Certificate update using c#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, ssl-certificate, azure-sdk-.net

I am building application which scans azure subscription and check SSL certificate expiry date. What I am trying to do is renew SSL certificate using C#.

My question is-

1. How certificates are managed over azure? Are they stored in some
   location? if so is it possible to access using FTP?
2. Is there any SDK or API for updating certificate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use azure management REST APIs to add , remove, manage certificates https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460817.aspx

but to map it to a custom domain of a web app one has to do it in the azure portal . I don't think there is an API for that.

Normally you upload the new certificate and then bind the new certificate with the custom domain under ssl settings category and save it.

Comment: Your link is specific to Azure API Manager.  For other services like Web Apps, a different API would be used.

Comment: updated url to the one that talks about the REST API for managing certificates in cloud services.

Comment: @Aravind got it, but it's not solving my problem.

Comment: What issue are you facing now ?

Comment: We can't bind certificate to custom domain using API right?

Comment: I want to upload and bind certificate (both upload and bind) using API.